# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm have a problem in react navigation, error message "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')".
Error happens when trying to call a screen by a button from another route

Component code:

```
     export default function Estruturas({ title, display, navigation }) {
      const [estruturas, setEstruturas] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function loadEstruturas() {
          const response = await api.get('/produto/api/estrutura');
    
          setEstruturas(response.data);
        }
        loadEstruturas();
      }, []);
    
    
      return (
...
   
          <ProductList>
            {estruturas.map(estrutura => (
              <Item key={estrutura.id} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Pedidos')}> 
...
```

Routes code:

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs(){
    return(
        <Tab.Navigator
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#694fad' }} 
        initialRouteName='Feed'   
        activeColor='black' 
        >
            <Tab.Screen 
                name="Início"
                component={Dashboard}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Início',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home"  size={26} />
                    ),
                  }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
                name="Pedidos"
                component={Requests}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Pedidos',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons name="assignment"  size={26} />
                    ),
                  }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>)}

export default function Routes() {      
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyTabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

I tried with Stack but it gave the same error

Comment: I don't see the component `Estruturas` in routes

Comment: A component is in Dashboard `return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {destination ?(
          <Fragment>
            <Address address={destination.title}/>
            <Estruturas />
          </Fragment> `

Answer (score 0):

Only the direct child of your navigator stack will have access to the navigation prop. I can see that your component **Estruturas** is not a direct route so it will not get the navigation prop directly inside the function props. There are 2 ways to get this done and fixed.

- Either use a **withNavigation** HOC provided by react-navigation v4 or if you are using v5 then use **useNavigation** hook.
- OR you need to pass the navigation prop to the component wherever you are calling this component. This can be done as below:-

```js
export default function Dashboard(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Estruturas navigation={props.navigation} />
    </View>
  );
}
```